# Firebase: Pull random data from Firebase to RecyclerView (android)

Tags: android, random, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I made a query to pull only 6 itens from database inside a RecyclerView, but at this time I can only orderByChild, limitToFirst or last. Everything is working fine but...

I'd like to put Random itens inside the Recyclerview every time I refresh the activity.

How can I put random data inside RecyclerView? Firebase does not have a special Random query. Is there any other way to do it?

Here is my code:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category");
query = mDatabase.limitToFirst(6); 

@Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final CategoryViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {


            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImagem());


            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


         });


        }


    };


    mImagesList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}
```

My adapter:

```
public static class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image1) {

        ImageView image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image1).into(image);

    }
}
```

Comment: There is no operator to get random data from your Firebase database. Did you have a look at previous questions asking the same? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+random+data

Comment: What else do you have on your Model class? Other than the image url?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I couldn't find a solution. @frankvanPuffelen

Comment: Just the image url. @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you also add another variable to your Model class. Something like an "id". And you store random `Long` values in it. (From 0 to 15 for example).
And then create a method that will generate a random value (lets say the method's name is `generateRandom()`). This way, when you want to get the random data, you can use your query like this:

```
query = mDatabase.orderByChild("id").startAt(generateRandom()).limitToFirst(6);
```

Comment: Suppose there are 10 items in database having id 1 to 10, I want 6 items randomly. If generateRandom() returns 8 , won't the query throw an exception? Because then the query will return only 3 items having id 8,9,10.

Comment: @N.K.TI see no problem there. Unless the `generateRandom()` returns a number > 9 (because 11 and 12 don't exist). If that's the case, maybe change the method to return a number between 1 and 8 instead.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Is it good if we use this query for large databases such as database with 100k user if we generate random no. between 1 to 100 then also first 6 users with id between 1 to 100 hundred will show rest will be never visible.