# Retrieve Random Object from Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, random, firebase-realtime-database

I want to be able to return random objects from the following image:

[image]

And not just the first object (-Kci1vM1dVBYBcPW7QA) which returns as is already. I have inserted the code from my app where it is currently reading from. The variables one, two and three are currently reading the first object but I want them to be able to retrieve random objects.

```
public void displayDeals(){

    databaseReference.child("FruitDeals").child("bR4sR4flMkYFrw1SzuWA8hpOnY52").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            deals_information = dataSnapshot.getValue(Deals_Information.class);
            one = deals_information.getDeal();
            two = deals_information.getPrice();
            three = deals_information.getAisleNum();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I might be able to answer this, but let me ask first, why are you using `addChildEventListener`, not `addValueEventListener`? Is there something you want to achieve by this?

Comment: @koceeng I have since actually changed it to ValueEventListener! My apologies

Comment: The problem solved then, no?

Comment: Yes! However, do you know how to obtain the string reference (i.e. "bR4sR4flMkYFrw1SzuWA8hpOnY52") rather than hard coding it in like so?

Comment: That really depends on how you save that value in the first place. Note that `ref.push().setValue(yourValue)` will generate random key, while `ref.child("yourNewKey").setValue(yourValue)` will place your value inside your desired key. Maybe consider using the later if you don't want that random key

Comment: thank you for your help @koceeng

Comment: You can check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042219/firebase-pull-random-data-from-firebase-to-recyclerview-android/42043146#42043146)