# Pick random record from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have the following code, I need to select random form objects, my idea is then to show the result in html and when the person reloads the page I can see another different result.

```
{
  "-L2LfbYxbwXDXiWNpt27" : {
    "count" : 18
  },
  "-L2PFNOQI28O_F_3YyuK" : {
    "count" : 13
  },
  "-L2PG848o7AGzKZTBnem" : {
    "count" : 17
  }
}



// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    databaseURL: "https://visit-hotels.firebaseio.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var app = angular.module("nowtimereal", ["firebase"]);

// this factory returns a synchronized array of nowusers
app.factory("peopleNow", ["$firebaseArray",
  function($firebaseArray) {
    // create a reference to the database location where we will store our data
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('nowusers');

    // this uses AngularFire to create the synchronized array
    return $firebaseArray(ref);
  }
]);

app.controller("NowCtrl", ["$scope", "peopleNow", function($scope, nowPeople) {
   $scope.now = nowPeople;
   $scope.now.$loaded(
        function(x) {
            $scope.oneResult = x[0];
            console.log($scope.oneResult)
    });

}]);
```

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42043146/5861618). It is written in Java, but you should be able to get the idea.