# How to get random data with angularfire2 valuechanges method

Tags: firebase, rxjs, observable, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I have `questions$` observable which returns more than `10` question objects from `Firestore`.

```js
this.questions$ = this.moduleCollection$.doc(module.id)
  .collection('questions').valueChanges();
```

Now i want to limit the result with `10` questions randomly.

I can limit the query like this

```js
this.questions$ = this.moduleCollection$.doc(module.id)
  .collection('questions',ref => ref.limit(10)).valueChanges();
```

But i don't know how to get it randomly, is there any `Rxjs` operators do so?

**What i have tried *(Extending @Richard Matsen's answer)***

```
const sampleSize = 2
const randomIndex = (array) => Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
const addIndexes = (array) => array.map((item, index) => {
    item['id'] = index  
    return item
  })
const removeIndexes = (array) => array.map(item => {
   delete item.id 
   return item
 })

this.questions$ = 
this.moduleCollection$.doc(module.id).collection('questions').valueChanges()
    .map(addIndexes)
    .map(r => r[randomIndex(r)])
    .repeat()
    .scan((a, c) => a.map(a => a.id).indexOf(c.id) === -1 ? a.concat(c) : a, [])
    .skipWhile(array => array.length < sampleSize)
    .take(1)
    .map(array => array.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id))
    .map(removeIndexes)
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48248306/5861618). It's written in Java, but it shouldn't be so hard to transform it in Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample demos a pure rxjs way to take a random sample from an array, with no duplicates.

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.of([{val: 'a'}, {val: 'b'}, {val: 'c'}, {val: 'd'}, {val: 'e'}])

const sampleSize = 2
const randomIndex = (array) => Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
const addIndexes = (array) => array.map((item, index) => {
    item['id'] = index  
    return item
  })
const removeIndexes = (array) => array.map(item => {
   delete item.id 
   return item
 })

const randomSample = (source, sampleSize) =>
  source
    .map(addIndexes)
    .map(r => r[randomIndex(r)])
    .repeat()
    .scan((a, c) => a.map(a => a.id).indexOf(c.id) === -1 ? a.concat(c) : a, [])
    .skipWhile(array => array.length < sampleSize)
    .take(1)
    .map(array => array.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id))
    .map(removeIndexes) 

randomSample(source, sampleSize).subscribe(console.log)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

---

**With firestore .valueChanges()**

The firestore `.valueChanges()` method is designed to push new arrays each time the data changes on the cloud, so this observable source ***will never complete***.
This means that `repeat()` never fires. To make it work, we need to wrap the sampling code.

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.of([{val: 'a'}, {val: 'b'}, {val: 'c'}, {val: 'd'}, {val: 'e'}])

const sampleSize = 2
const randomIndex = (array) => Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
const addIndexes = (array) => array.map((item, index) => {
    item['id'] = index  
    return item
  })
const removeIndexes = (array) => array.map(item => {
   delete item.id 
   return item
 })

const randomSample = (source, sampleSize) =>
  source
    .mergeMap(array => 
      Rx.Observable.of(array)
        .map(addIndexes)
        .map(r => r[randomIndex(r)])
        .repeat()
        .scan((a, c) => a.map(a => a.id).indexOf(c.id) === -1 ? a.concat(c) : a, [])
        .skipWhile(array => array.length < sampleSize)
        .take(1)
        .map(array => array.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id))
        .map(removeIndexes) 
     )

randomSample(source, sampleSize).subscribe(console.log)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

---

**Using non-Rx sampling**

One thing that stands out in the above code is that we are converting an observable of an array to an array, then back to an inner observable of array (all to get a 'complete' event).

So, it is more practical to work on the array directly.
(Has been tested with firestore `.valueChanges()` as well)

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.of([{val: 'a'}, {val: 'b'}, {val: 'c'}, {val: 'd'}, {val: 'e'}])

const sampleSize = 2
const getRandomUniqueSample = (arr, sampleSize) => {
  let result = [],
      taken = {}; 
  while (result.length < Math.min(sampleSize, arr.length)) {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    if (!(x in taken)) {
      result.push(arr[x])
      taken[x] = null;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const randomSample = (source, sampleSize) =>
  source
    .mergeMap(array => 
      Rx.Observable.of(getRandomUniqueSample(array, sampleSize))
    )

randomSample(source, sampleSize).subscribe(console.log)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried it and with some errors. i updated what i tired with my question. please help

Comment: Ah yes, you have an array of objects, so the scan must be made a little more sophisticated. Do you have an id property on the object, such as `questionId`?

Comment: not right now, but i can do it easily with `.snapshotChanges`. lets assume i have a field `questionId`, which will be some thing like `lpybtKeZpr7lPDZMQtcO`

Comment: That would work, but this is just a small local change - really shouldn't influence the way you access firestore. The array items have an index anyway, I'll use that and you can dial it back if you feel it's more appropriate.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about the concat error, which may be due to a missing import.

Comment: Your code works, but when i put i in to my code it giving null. if i comment `.skipWhile(array => array.length < sampleSize)` i am getting single random value each time. any idea?

Comment: I'll have a look and come back to it tomorrow (will test against firestore). BTW, you can debug a little by putting `do(x => console.log(x))` at different steps. It won't change the outcome.