# Retrieve random data from firebase database with options

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an Quiz app wherein questions and answers are taken from firebase. I have uploaded questions with its options in firebase and now want to retrieve them randomly but don't know how to do so as I am a beginner in programming.
This is the Screenshot of my firebase data

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T7-x3TP1TaA8_ntwfoRNdb2oMGV_swl6/view?usp=sharing

```
 private void updateQuestion(){

       mQuestionRef = new Firebase("https://testapp-465fe.firebaseio.com/"+ mQuestionNumber + "/question");

        mQuestionRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String question = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mQuestionView.setText(question);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });


        mChoiceRef1 = new Firebase("https://testapp-465fe.firebaseio.com/"+ mQuestionNumber + "/choice1");

        mChoiceRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String choice1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mButtonChoice1.setText(choice1);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        mChoiceRef2 = new Firebase("https://testapp-465fe.firebaseio.com/"+ mQuestionNumber + "/choice2");

        mChoiceRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String choice2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mButtonChoice2.setText(choice2);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        mChoiceRef3 = new Firebase("https://testapp-465fe.firebaseio.com/"+ mQuestionNumber + "/choice3");

        mChoiceRef3.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String choice3 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mButtonChoice3.setText(choice3);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        mChoiceRef4 = new Firebase("https://testapp-465fe.firebaseio.com/"+ mQuestionNumber + "/choice4");

        mChoiceRef4.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String choice4 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mButtonChoice4.setText(choice4);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        mAnswerRef = new Firebase("https://testapp-465fe.firebaseio.com/"+ mQuestionNumber + "/answer");

        mAnswerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               mAnswer = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });


            mQuestionNumber++;


   }
```

This is my code to load questions sequentially from the firebase! I googled a lot but not getting how to generate a random node and get the child values of that random node!

Comment: You can create a Random Number and then find it in your FireBase Database.Show what have you tried.

Comment: I haven't tried generating a random number as I am beginner and I don't exactly know how i should implement it.

Comment: Just google it, and If you stuck ask here. Good Luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i retrieve a random value Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245706/how-can-i-retrieve-a-random-value-firebase-database)

Answer (score 0):

Being a beginner, generating random number can be a small mess. So an easy way to do this would be getting the **current time**  in **millisecond** so that it looks something like `11023049` **(hour-min-sec-ms)**

Since this would be unique each time it is generated, you would need a function to determine an order of question retrieved based on this unique value.

To be specific to your question, you can just get the time in **millisecond**, as it is the fastest changing variable and retrieve the question whose number is equal to millisecond. Or to have some variation, **odd millisecond values would fetch questions in reverse order, and even values would fetch in normal order**.

**UPDATE 1**:
A trivial way of creating an order is (This would only randomize the starting question, next questions will be in order so other methods are strongly recommended):

```
public void ArrayList<Integer> getOrderTrivial(int lastQsNum)
{
    System.out.println("Started");
    int currentSec = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("ss").format(new Date()));
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (currentSec%2 == 0)
    {
        /*If the second value is even, the order of questions will be straight*/
        for (int i=currentSec; i<=lastQsNum; i++)
        {
            order.add(i);               
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=currentSec; i++)
        {
            order.add(i);               
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /*If the second value is even, the order of questions will be reverse*/
        for (int i=currentSec; i>=0; i--)
        {
            order.add(i);               
        }
        for (int i=lastQsNum; i>=currentSec; i--)
        {
            order.add(i);               
        }           
    }
    System.out.println("Complete");
    return order;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** A better way (recommended)

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getOrder(int lastQsNum)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<>();
    int sec = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("ss").format(new Date()));
    int start = sec, down = sec - 1, up = sec + 1;      
    order.add(start);
    while (up<=lastQsNum && down>=0)
    {                       
        if (!order.contains(up)) order.add(up);         
        if (!order.contains(down)) order.add(down);
        up = up+1;
        down = down-1;                              
    }       
    if (up>lastQsNum)
    {
        System.out.println("Upper Limit Reaached: "+up+"-"+down);
        int mid = down/2;
        if (!order.contains(mid)) order.add(mid);
        up = mid+1;
        down = mid -1;          
    }
    else if (down<0)
    {
        System.out.println("Lower Limit Reaached: "+up+"-"+down);
        int mid = up + ((lastQsNum - up)/2);
        if (!order.contains(mid)) order.add(mid);
        up = mid+1;
        down = mid -1;
    }
    while (up<=lastQsNum && down>=0)
    {
        if (sec%3 == 0)
        {
            if (!order.contains(up)) order.add(3, up);          
            if (!order.contains(down)) order.add(6, down);
        }
        else if (sec%5 == 0)
        {
            if (!order.contains(up)) order.add(5, up);          
            if (!order.contains(down)) order.add(10, down);
        }
        else if (sec%7 == 0)
        {
            if (!order.contains(up)) order.add(7, up);          
            if (!order.contains(down)) order.add(14, down);
        }
        else if (sec%11 == 0)
        {
            if (!order.contains(up)) order.add(11, up);         
            if (!order.contains(down)) order.add(22, down);
        }
        else if (sec%2 == 0)
        {
            if (!order.contains(up)) order.add(0, up);          
            if (!order.contains(down)) order.add(0, down);  
        }
        else
        {
            if (!order.contains(up)) order.add(up);         
            if (!order.contains(down)) order.add(down);
        }           
        up = up+1;
        down = down-1;          
    }
    return order;
}
```

The return object for both methods is an ArrayList.
In the `onCreate()` stub of your Activity, you should run this function and create an ArrayList. Something like:

```
//Global Variables
ArrayList<Integer> order;
int maxQuestions = 200;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    order = getOrderTrivial(maxQuestions);
}
```

Once the `ArrayList` called `order` is created you can serially traverse through the `ArrayList` and get the question number and use it to fetch question from `Firebase Database` (from a ValueEventListener).

Comment: The idea of milliseconds is quite good, but I am confused of how to retrieve it from firesbase with the options of the same question! Can you help me with a sample code or some method or logic on how should I implement it?

Comment: yes, i would upload the code in a couple of minutes. :)

Comment: **UPDATE 1** is the most easy and lame way. Other methods will be updated soon.

Comment: Read the new update It is based on seconds rather than milliseconds.

Comment: I used Random function to randomize the node value of firebase and then called it! It worked for me but the only problem now I am facing is that sometimes same question gets repeated twice!

Comment: for that you need to keep an ArrayList that would contain the contain the question number which are already asked. It also could be a string with a delimiter.

Comment: ok I will try it! can you help me with this problem--   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344585/load-a-task-of-firebase-while-splash-screen-appears

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking how to do this and i have come to this

first you will need to fetch all the data from the `Database`, for this just do like below

```
  DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


         //Since you dont have a parent for all the questions, you should reference to your url to get all the items
           ref.child("https://testapp-465fe.firebaseio.com/").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                questionList = new ArrayList<String>();                
                // Result will be holded Here
                for (DataSnapshot ql : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                      questionList.add(String.valueOf(ql.geValue())); //We add all the results to an arraylist

                    }
        /* Now all the data from your database will be stored in the ArrayList, just go and get from there what you need, the answers, the questions, etc */
```

I will leave you this snippet on how to get the content from the ArrayList

```
 /*This method retrieves values from ArrayList using Iterator
     */
    public static void retrieveValuesFromList(List list)
    {
        Iterator itr = list.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next()); //you can use a Log.e("Data: ",""+itr.next()); here
        }
    }
```

where `list` will be your `ArrayList` questionList

```
retrieveValuesFromList(yourlist);
```

Hope this helps

happy coding !