# Random Firebase query

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I need to use `Collections.shuffle()` at the recyclerView , But it is not possible because I use firebase query :

```
 query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Videos").orderByChild("s").equalTo("1");
```

so `Collections.shuffle((List<?>) query2);` will show an error

Also I tried to user `startAt()` inside query but I could't detect the key and value of `child s` in the same query.

so please help me with any solutions or alternatives

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245706/how-can-i-retrieve-a-random-value-firebase-database/48248306);

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you, Could you please let me know how can I use it with firebase query?

Comment: You want to pass a random number to a query?

Comment: I need to get all children which includes child `s == 1`  and detect the key of random child to use in startAt()

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate through a concrete example.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I realized that it is not possible to use`child(x).equles(x)` and `orderbyKey().startAt()` in the same query

so I've change my database structure to make a specific query for each section then sorted by `startAt(randomValue)`

Comment: That's good. Cheers!