# How to get unique random product in node Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Data:

```
- products
   - -L74Pc7oVY22UsCETFBv
       - name: "gjwj"
       - category: "hreggrrg"
       - location: "vjhiwehifwe"
       - price: 44
       - color: fassaf
   - -L74uJ7oVYcVNyCteFBz
       - name: "uygfwh"
       - category: "hhhjwwwom"
       - location: "pervrr"
       - price: 33
       - color: yrtrr
   ......................
```

I have many products in node `products`, over 1000 products. I can display all in `ListView`. I want to display only one unique random to user, like highlights, but not to download all, only one.

Code:

```
ValueEventListener v = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = (String) child.child("name").getValue().toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //How to get?????
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(v);
```

How to get unique random product in node Firebase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there are a few good answers here on SOF but are separated, so I will try to answer your question with two approaches.

But first of all, before writing some code, I can tell you that this code is not working because you are missig a child in your reference, which is `products`, obviously assuming that the `products` node is a direct child of your Firebase database root.

**The actual answer:**

Assuming that your database structure looks like this (in which the `products` node is a direct child of your Firebase database):

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- products
         |
         --- productIdOne
         |      |
         |      --- name: "gjwj"
         |      |
         |      --- category: "hreggrrg"
         |      |
         |      --- location: "vjhiwehifwe"
         |      |
         |      --- price: 44
         |      |
         |      --- color: "fassaf"
         |
         --- productIdTwo
         |      |
         |      --- name: "uygfwh"
         |      |
         |      --- category: "hhhjwwwom"
         |      |
         |      --- location: "pervrr"
         |      |
         |      --- price: 33
         |      |
         |      --- color: "yrtrr"
         |
         --- //And so on
```

To get a random product, please use the following code:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, randomProductList);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference productsRef = rootRef.child("products"); //Added call to .child("products")
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            productList.add(name);
        }

        int productListSize = productList.size();
        List<String> randomProductList = new ArrayList<>();

        randomProductList.add(new Random().nextInt(productListSize)); //Add the random product to list
        arrayAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: ", task.getException()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
productsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In order to get all the products, you need to loop through all children of the `products` node. So a call to `child("products")` is mandatory.

If you want more then one random product, then you can create a loop and add as many random products as you want in your `randomProductList`.

This is called the classic solution and you can use it for nodes that contain only a few records but if you are afraid of getting huge amount of data then I'll recommend you this second approach. This also involves a little change in your database by adding a new node named `productIds`. Your database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- products
   |     |
   |     --- productIdOne
   |     |      |
   |     |      --- //details
   |     |
   |     --- productIdTwo
   |            |
   |            --- //details
   |      
   --- productIds
          |
          --- productIdOne: true
          |
          --- productIdTwo: true
          |
          --- //And so on
```

So as you mentioned in your question, if you want to avoid downloading the entire `products` node which contains all the products with all the properties, you have to create a separate node named `productIds`. So to get a single product, you'll need only to download a simple node that contains only the product ids.

This practice is called denormalization (duplicating data) and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, i recomand you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

But rememebr, in the way you are adding the random products in this new created node, in the same way you need to remove them when there are not needed anymore.

So to get the random product, you need to query your database twice. Please see the code below:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference productIdsRef = rootRef.child("productIds");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> productIdsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String productId = ds.getKey();
            productIdsList.add(productId);
        }

        int productListSize = productList.size();
        List<String> randomProductList = new ArrayList<>(););

        DatabaseReference productIdRef = rootRef.child("products").child(productIdsList.get(new Random().nextInt(int productListSize));
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", name);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: ", task.getException()); //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        };
        productIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: ", task.getException()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
productIdsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the `dataSnapshot` contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the `dataSnapshot` object will contain a list of one result.

Comment: DatabaseReference productIdRef = rootRef.child("products").child(productIdsList.get(new Random().nextInt(int productListSize)) it shows error in the following line  int productListSize already defined in scope.

Comment: Can we use Pager concept here?

Comment: @RaviMalik Without seeing your code, I cannot be much of a help. If you have a hard time implementing that, show us what you have tried by posting a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Mostly everything is clear to me from the code  but can you please explain a bit whats happening in this line  DatabaseReference productIdRef = rootRef.child("products").child(productIdsList.get(new Random().nextInt(int productListSize))

Comment: @RaviMalik In that line of code, we are creating a reference using a random index from the list.