# How to save retrieved data from firebase to string variable in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Hy Developers,** I am new to android development so that's why facing an issue in **saving and viewing data to my android app**.

I know that data can only be retrieved while you are connected to internet.

But the thing is it is retrieving data and also showing to android log.

> But when i try to save it to a string variable or to arraylist to show
>   it on main activity using that list or variable, its not working.

**I am declaring a private string variable to store value from firebase database before onCreate method.**

Sorry for my nob question. But this is the issue i am facing.

**Following is the code** that i am using and some screenshots to make the question understandable.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Firelog" ;

Button ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4;

TextView uscore, question, timer;

private String mAnswer;

private ArrayList<String> fbquestions = new ArrayList<String>();

private String quest;

private int mScore = 0;

Random r = new Random();

private int res = 0;

private int c = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uscore);
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

    ans1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ans1);
    ans2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ans2);
    ans3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ans3);
    ans4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ans4);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("mcqs");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map <String, String> map = (Map)dataSnapshot.getValue();
            quest = map.get("question");

            fbquestions.add(quest);

            Log.v("E_Value","Question is" + quest);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    question.setText(String.valueOf(fbquestions.get(0)));
  }
}
```

[image]

In above pic you can see that **question is retrieved successfully from firebase and visible in log.**

[image]

But here when i try to display question on main screen after assigning, **its showing blank.**

[image]

After adding the code to add value to arraylist, application crashes..

Comment: pass quest value to text view

Comment: I am doing that, you can see this in the code i provided above..

Comment: check answer @Ehsan and let me know one thing are you getting value in logs.?

Comment: Yes as you could see in the black picture above, i am getting the question in log "What is your name"

Comment: question.setText(String.valueOf(fbquestions.get(0))); why you are doing this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply get the value of `fbquestions.get(0)` outside the `onDataChange()` method because this method has an asynchronous behavior. So you cannot simply create your `fbquestions` list as a global variable and use it's value outside the callbakc because it will always be `empty`. Basically, you're trying to use a value synchronously from an API that's asynchronous. That's not a good idea. You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

A quick solve for this problem would be to move the following line of code:

```
question.setText(String.valueOf(fbquestions.get(0)));
```

Inside the callback right after this line of code:

```
Log.v("E_Value","Question is" + quest);
```

And your problem will be solved. If you want to use the list outside, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Perfectly got the solution.
But there is a little issue again. 
I want to use that list to display values on main screen after it had finished adding all elements to the list from firebase db.

Comment: Oh, it's pretty simple. **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `ListView` using an `ArrayAdapter` and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: I know that we can use list view or Recyclerview. But that's for list items. I want to show a single question from my list to the main screen using a random number.
I am working on a quiz app.

Comment: This sounds as another question but since I have already answered a similar one, **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413117/how-to-get-unique-random-product-in-node-firebase/50413208)** is how you can get a random item from a section of your database.

Comment: You have references in all those answers so you can generate a random item and display it in a `RecyclerView` or `ListView`. So given the information in those answers, please make your own attempt and ask another question if something else comes up. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Pass quest value to Textview..

```
ArrayList<String> questionArrrayList =new Arraylist<>();
questionArrrayList .clear();

   myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map <String, String> map = (Map)dataSnapshot.getValue();
            quest = map.get("question");
             question.setText(quest);


                questionArrrayList .add(quest);
                Log.v("E_Value","Question is" + quest);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: that would work i know, but i want to save questions.. So later on i can view that on main screen using get function of arraylist.

Comment: then store that Question in arrayList

Comment: This code is useful, but this will only display the current retrieved value to the main screen.

Comment: what you actually want to do.?

Comment: I have mcqs in my db, i want to retrieve each question from db and to store them in arraylist so i could show them to user by generating random numbers.

Comment: do one thing store data in list and check log for that arraylist

Comment: please check the code again, i updated it and now application get crashed.

Comment: kindly share crash logs. and post your code of array list