# How to shuffle a value from firebase database and how to show recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I stored data's in firebase Real Time database and want to retrieve them in shuffled. For example i need to give data's in shuffled for every user uses that application and every time when the user refresh the page it gives randomly shuffled values..

> Because the data was more than 1000 + .. so every time giving a new
>   data for user.

code

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vacancy");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<VacancyModel> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<VacancyModel>()
            .setQuery(reference.orderByChild("companyname"), VacancyModel.class)
            .build();


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<VacancyModel, VacancyViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<VacancyModel, VacancyViewHolder>(options) {

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VacancyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final VacancyModel model) {




                    holder.vacompany_name.setText(model.getCompanyname());
                    holder.vajob_type.setText("Job Title: " + model.getJob_title());
                    holder.vatiming.setText(model.getTiming());
                    holder.vatotal_vacancy.setText("Total Vacancy: " +model.getTotal_vacancy());
                    holder.vasp.setText(model.getS_p());
                    holder.vaexpected_vasalary.setText("Expected Salary: " +model.getExpexted_salary());
                    holder.vaarea.setText("Area: " +model.getPincode());
                    holder.vaphone_number.setText("Contact Number: " +model.getContact_number());



                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {


                            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, VacancyViewActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("pid", model.getCompanyID());
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }

                    });
                }


                @NonNull
                @Override
                public VacancyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vacancy_list_item, viewGroup, false);
                    VacancyViewHolder holder = new VacancyViewHolder(view);
                    return holder;
                }

            };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();


}
```

[image: firebase Database]

Comment: @AlexMamo: the [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection) is about Cloud Firestore, while this one is about Realtime Database. While the same mechanisms can be applied to both, it's not a 1:1 duplicate without at least some clarifying comments.

Comment: You'll typically need to include some random value into each node that you can then order and filter on. Dan's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46798981) shows how to do that for Firestore, and the same can be applied to the Realtime Database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh my bad, sorry about that. I have copied and pasted the wrong url. Now should be better. This is the correct **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413117/how-to-get-unique-random-product-in-node-firebase/50413208)**. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you are taking **wrong RecyclerOptions** for this

FirebaseRecyclerOptions use to observe the realtime database thus changes on realtime database is rendered in as sequenced in realtime database

**why don't you use basic recyclerview setups like this**.

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

        StudentDetails studentDetails dataSnapshot.getValue(StudentDetails.class);

        list.add(studentDetails);
    }

    //shuffle it after getting all the data

    Collections.shuffle(list);

    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ShowStudentDetailsActivity.this, list);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

   //got all the data 
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    //cancel

}});
```