# How to get the key of a child node in Firebase Realtime Database after choosing a child randomly

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, random

I want to get the key of the child node in the Firebase Realtime Database, which is also the `UID`. I am randomly choosing a child node and now I want to get the key of that child so that I can do further operations on it.

```
databaseReferencePickers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         try {
            int pickerCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            Random random = new Random();
            int rand = random.nextInt(pickerCount);
            Iterator itr = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            for(int i = 0; i <= rand; i++) {
                itr.next();
            }

            pickerDetails = itr.next().toString();

            ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            map = oMapper.convertValue(itr.next(), Map.class);
            //pickerUID = Objects.requireNonNull(map.get("key")).toString();
            pickerUID = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            Toast.makeText(OrderPickupActivity.this,pickerUID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         } catch (Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(OrderPickupActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
});
```

Can you please help me with it? Whenever I Toast the value of "PickerUID", I get the value as **null**.

[Here is the image.](https://ibb.co/FYmVX7g)

I want to retrieve the key from the pickers section.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: Please add it to your question and not as an external link. You can use [imgbb.com](https://imgbb.com/).

Comment: I tried, check the question now

Comment: "That page doesn't exist".

Comment: I changed the link now

Comment: How is `databaseReferencePickers` defined?

Comment: databaseReferencePickers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pickers/");

Comment: Please also add the line of code where you Toast that `PickerUID`.

Comment: I have made the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a random `uid` by attaching a listener on the `Pickers` node, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference pickersRef = rootRef.child("Pickers");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> uids = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uid = ds.getKey();
            uids.add(uid);
        }

        String randomUid = new Random().nextInt(uids.size());
        //Do what you need to do with this random uid
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: ", task.getException()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
pickersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

See, you have to iterate through the `DataSnapshot` object using the `getChildren()` method in order to obtain the results. However, this is not quite the best solution because you download the entire `Pickers` node, in order to get a single random id. For a more appreciate solution, please also check my answer from the following post:

- [How to get unique random product in node Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413117/how-to-get-unique-random-product-in-node-firebase/50413208)

Comment: Should I create a new ML kit for it or a cloud function?

Comment: "It's not working", doesn't help me, help you solve the issue. Show me your new database schema and the **EXACT** code that you are using. I personally test it and it works pretty fine.