# Firebase remove child recyclerview Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I need to remove child from Firebase after onClick from RecyclerView Adapter.

I have something like this:

Firebase database is [image]

recyclerview is [image]

My biggest problem is not sure how to get the "key" of the child node from the recyclerview.

I have been stuck on this supposedly simple thing for about 3 days so hopefully any help is appreciated.

```
package com.cpg12.findingfresh.adapters

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.cpg12.findingfresh.R
import com.cpg12.findingfresh.database.ShoppingList
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase

class ShoppingListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoppingListAdapter.ShoppingListViewHolder>() {

    private val shoppingList = ArrayList<ShoppingList>()



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ShoppingListViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.shopping_list_item, parent, false)

        /** References the node to which market data is stored**/
        val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
        
        return ShoppingListViewHolder(itemView)
    }



    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ShoppingListAdapter.ShoppingListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = shoppingList[position]
        holder.sListItem.text = currentItem.shoppingItem

    }



    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return shoppingList.size
    }

    fun updateShoppinglist(shoppingList: List<ShoppingList>){
        this.shoppingList.clear()
        this.shoppingList.addAll(shoppingList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    class ShoppingListViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        val sListItem : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShoppingItemTV)

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            databaseReference.child(marketName).setValue(markets).child(key).setValue("")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the key of a child node in Firebase Realtime Database after choosing a child randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864594/how-to-get-the-key-of-a-child-node-in-firebase-realtime-database-after-choosing)

Comment: If you consider at some point in time try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here are some useful articles that might help. [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) and [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166).

Comment: Using FirebaseUI database may solve your problem. Using this you can get the key of the child and remove it on click.

Comment: I will probably use firestore and firebase UI next time. For now, I just decided to use a delete all button instead. Thank you for everyones input