# How to delete an item from ListView and also delete it on Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

My problem is that if I try to delete an item on my `ListView`, all the data will be deleted to on both listview and my firebase realtime database. All I want is, if I long click an item, only that item will be removed, not all of them on the `ListView`. Thank you. Any help is appreciated

This is what I declare:

```
 MatkulAdapter matkulAdapter = null;
 Matkul matkul;
 DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 DatabaseReference dbReference = root.child("MataKuliah");
```

This is the code to delete an item:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Matkul item = matkulAdapter.getItem(position);
                    matkulAdapter.remove(item);
                    dbReference.removeValue();
                    matkulAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     return true;
                }
            });
```

This is my database:

[This is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8bl6.png)

EDIT QUESTION

and also i tried this code with .child but the data only deleted on ListView. So the data comes back when i re-open the ListView.

```
   listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Matkul item = matkulAdapter.getItem(position);
                matkulAdapter.remove(item);
                dbReference.child(item.getNamaMatkul()).removeValue();
                matkulAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need pass your firebase item id (15955880552231) in second child, like this code:

```
Query query = rdbReference.orderByChild("namaMatkul").equalTo(item.namaMatkul);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        matkulAdapter.remove(item);
        matkulAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
}});
```

Comment: thankyou sir, but sorry, how to get the firebaseItemID? How should i declare it?

Comment: Use the code in your click listener to find specific item

Comment: thankyou so much sirr! the code is working but having a little bug that if i delete an item, it will be change to other data or the data will be double, but when i go back first then open it again, it would gone from the listview. Many thanks sirr

Comment: This is only snippet,  you need to develop the logic ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
dbReference.removeValue();
```

Everything beneath `MataKuliah` will be deleted. If only need to remove the `1595588052231` child, then simply use the following line of code:

```
dbReference.child("1595588052231").removeValue();
```

A better approach might be to store the `1595588052231` as a value of a `uid` property in your database and then use:

```
dbReference.child(item.getUid()).removeValue();
```

Comment: Thankyou sir, but what if i want to delete random item on the MataKuliah? i try this code `dbReference.child(item.getUid()).removeValue();` but having error on the getUid()

Comment: You have an error because you should add in your `Matkul` class a new property named `uid` and the corresponding `getUid()` getter. In your database under your `1595588052231` node, you should also have the `uid` property that should hold the same `1595588052231` value. Then everything will work fine. If you need to get a random value, please check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413117/how-to-get-unique-random-product-in-node-firebase/50413208)** out.

Comment: i already add the `private String uid` and getter the `getUid()` on `Matkul` sir, but get this error `Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()`

Comment: This is happening because the value that you are trying to get from the database does **not** exist. As I said earlier, you should also add it to the database. So you have `namaDosen` and `namaMaktul`, add and the `uid` with the value of `1595588052231`.