# How to get the first and the last data from firebase on button click

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I have two menu option 'latest & first' as the name suggest when I click the latest I want to get the latest data from firebase and if I click first I want to get the first data

here is a screenshot of how the database looks
[image]

so when I say first I want to get the first data in the list (q1)

here is the method by which I want to implement this

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menue, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.latestQuote:
                latestQuote();
                return true;
            case R.id.firstQuote:
                firstQuote();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void latestQuote() {
    }

    private void firstQuote() {
        
    }
```

here is the database refrence

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Quotes");
        model = new Model();
        quotes_list = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    model = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model.class);
                    if (model != null) {
                        quotes_list.add(model.getTitle());
                        position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());

                    }
                }
                quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
                countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());

            }
```

Comment: So you want to get the first and the last element, in a single call? Or in separate calls?

Comment: seprate calls when the respected onClick

Comment: Is your `Quotes` a direct child of your root?

Comment: yes Quotes is the direct child of root

Comment: Ok, I'' write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your last comment, since you need to have separate calls, for example, to get the **first** question, please use the following lines of code:

```
private void firstQuote() {
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference quotesRef = db.child("Quotes");
    Query queryForFirstElement = quotesRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(1); //
    queryForFirstElement.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DataSnapshot qs : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                    String title = qs.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", title);
                    quotes_list.add(title);
                    position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());
                }
                quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
                countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
The unexamined life is not worth living.
```

To get the **last** element, then simply use the exact code as above, but instead of using `.limitToFirst(1)`, you have to use `.limitToLast(1)`:

```
private void latestQuote() {
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference quotesRef = db.child("Quotes");
    Query queryForFirstElement = quotesRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1); //
    queryForFirstElement.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DataSnapshot qs : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                    String title = qs.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", title);
                    quotes_list.add(title);
                    position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());
                }
                quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
                countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer and sorry for replying late too it , Hey actually i want to get the first data and the latest data in there respected method as i shown in the code  private void latestQuote() {
    }

    private void firstQuote() {
        
    }

Comment: In that case, please see my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: hey please can you see the updated question , i add the code which i use to get data , this is how i want to get the data too

Comment: The edited question is not related to the initial question. I just rolled it back to the initial state. In general, other questions that derive from the initial question should be considered new questions and should be added here on StackOverflow separately.

Comment: So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: okay i add a new question just a min

Comment: yes actually its not working

Comment: "it's not working"  doesn't provide enough information so I can further help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: please check what i add http://pastie.org/p/0COrVNSIteAwkbJS2mhXf4

Comment: The code I provided was just an example in which I showed you how to correctly get the title. Having the title you can do whatever you want with it. But I have just updated the answer to use the exact same code as you do. Does it work niow?

Comment: But I'm not sure how it will work since the list will always have the size of 1.

Comment: just a sec i check and i inform u

Comment: uhh no its not working , if u say i can i add the code so you can undertsand a

Comment: Your question states "How to get the first and the last data from firebase". So If you try to look at the logcat, are you getting the first and the last question as requested? Please answer this.

Comment: okay wait its gettin the first quote but the issue is as we are using position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size()); its setinng text  random quote

Comment: In the first method, what does `Log.d("TAG", title);` print out in the logcat? It should print `The unexamined life is not worth living.` if you still have the database schema that exists in the screenshot you have added to your question, right?

Comment: okay wait its gettin the first quote but the issue is as we are using position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size()); its setinng text random quote

Comment: its just showing in the logcat but when setText its getting random quote

Comment: Good to hear that you got the first quote. Other things that don't work the way you expect, should be added to a different question. So all the logic regarding the part where you want to get a random question should be added to a newer question. Since you're new, I recommend you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413117/how-to-get-unique-random-product-in-node-firebase/50413208) out.

Comment: So can I help you with other information regarding the initial question (not other stuff that is related to getting a random question)?

Comment: okay i checked the latest one too and its getting the latest quote in the logcat

Comment: Good to hear that too ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for this big help , yes i will add a new question for not able to get the text , thanks a lot