# Issue with setText while getting data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, settext

I have 2000 quotes in Firebase. I have two buttons, first & latest. As the name suggests, when I click 'first', it shows the first data from Firebase in the logs, and the same for the 'latest', when I click it, it gets and shows the latest data from Firebase in the logs.

The issue is when I try to setText, it shows a random quote and I don't know what I should do. I asked this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474410/how-to-get-the-first-and-the-last-data-from-firebase-on-button-click) about how to get the first and last data from Firebase, and I received an answer too, but the issue is I'm not able to setText the correct data.

```java
private void latestQuote() {
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference quotesRef = db.child("Quotes");
    Query queryForFirstElement = quotesRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1); //
    queryForFirstElement.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DataSnapshot qs : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                    String title = qs.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", title);
                    quotes_list.add(title);
                    position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());
                }
                quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
                countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });
}

private void firstQuote() {
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference quotesRef = db.child("Quotes");
    Query queryForFirstElement = quotesRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(1); //
    queryForFirstElement.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DataSnapshot qs : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                    String title = qs.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", title);
                    quotes_list.add(title);
                    position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());
                }
                quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
                countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I'm pretty sure this is happening because of this line                             `position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());`, but even if I remove it, it just doesn't set any text in the text view, but still shows the expected data in the logs.

Here is an example on how I'm getting some other data and this method just works perfectly:

```java
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void back() {  
    if (position > 0) {
        position = (position - 1) % quotes_list.size();
        quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
        countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void next() {
    position = (position + 1) % quotes_list.size();
    quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
    countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void random() {
    position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());
    quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
    countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
}
```

Adding Model.class as requested in comments

```java
public class Model {
    String title;

    public Model() {
    }

    public Model(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: please put quotes_list model.

Comment: okay i have adedd please check the updated question

Comment: int position = 0;

Comment: try this. 
quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position).title);

Comment: if it work please reply or else i will try to give new solution.

you are only printing position please give title to text view after position

Comment: hey it will be very helpfull  if u put this in some detail in an answer

Comment: this works?
quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position).title);

Comment: no , actually idint undertadn where do i put this , should i remove the                         position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());
    and put this  quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position).title); there

Comment: dont remove but replace this line it will get first qoute
quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(0).title);

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
                        quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(0).title); its showing error on .title

Comment: try to put this line inside for loop
quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));

Comment: same error in for loop

Comment: try after for loop

for(int i=0;i<quote_list.size;i++){
 quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(0).title);
}

Comment: in fist foor loop add all quote in list ad in second loop get 0 from that list it might give you solution.

Comment: can you please add as this in answer , its geting confusing in comments, sorry

Comment: check bro i have posted a image